# psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL: database "<user>" does not exist

Tags: database, postgresql, table-plus

I tried running a postgres server to viewing my databases with TablePlus after not doing so for a while.

Running the server:

```
brew services start postgresql
Warning: Formula postgresql was renamed to postgresql@14.
Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error
Try re-running the command as root for richer errors.
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /Users/eliott/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@14.plist` exited with 5.
➜  ~ brew services restart postgresql
Warning: Formula postgresql was renamed to postgresql@14.
Stopping `postgresql@14`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `postgresql@14` (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@14)
==> Successfully started `postgresql@14` (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@14)
```

When I ran `psql` it returned this error:

```
psql: error: connection to server on socket “/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432” failed: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
```

… and something similar in TablePlus.

The version was 14.7 at this point so decided to install 15 with homebrew `brew install postgresql@15` (though the version is now only 14.8) but now the error has changed to:

```
psql: error: connection to server on socket “/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432” failed: FATAL: database “eliott” does not exist
```

in TablePlus:

> connection to server at “127.0.0.1”, port 5432 failed: FATAL: database “eliott” does not exist

When I run `psql -l`, the following is returned:

```
List of databases
   Name    | Owner  | Encoding | Collate | Ctype | Access privileges 
-----------+--------+----------+---------+-------+-------------------
 postgres  | eliott | UTF8     | C       | C     | 
 template0 | eliott | UTF8     | C       | C     | =c/eliott        +
           |        |          |         |       | eliott=CTc/eliott
 template1 | eliott | UTF8     | C       | C     | =c/eliott        +
           |        |          |         |       | eliott=CTc/eliott
(3 rows)
```

EDIT: the CLI works now but what I didn't realise before from running `psql -l` is that all the databases I used to have are gone now. I'm guessing I may have deleted them by accident(?) or is there the possibility that postgres/tableplus is looking for the wrong path?

Comment: try 'psql -d postgres'. as you can see "eliott" database is not there. "eliott" role is there. 
when you type "eliott" the system may assume default database name as "eliott".

Comment: @jian thank you. the CLI works now but what I didn't realise before from running `psql -l` is that all the databases I have are gone now. I'm guessing I may have deleted them by accident(?) or is there the possibility that postgres/tableplus is looking for the wrong path?

Comment: if `CLI` works, which means, you must connect to at least one database. if you didn't see any tables, that probably because of search_path. try google around postgres search_path. for example `psql -p 5421 -d test16` works, means you connect to database test16. but after you are IN,you maybe see nothing because of privilege or search_path config.